# Apply css style to all components in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular

I have very basic, and reusable css rules, such as:

```
.ng-invalid {
    border-left: 5px solid #a94442;
}

.ng-valid {
    border-left: 5px solid #42A948;
}
```

I'd like to re-use these for all of my components. If I place this in my root `AppComponent`, which is the one that is bootstrapped by Angular, then it's not recognized by any other components in my application other than the `AppComponent`.

I must be missing something very obvious here.

Comment: For me, I needed to apply CSS definitions on BODY, HTML and so on, and in the current app I could do it only from within internal components, so I just added these defitions under ::ng-deep and it worked like a charm. This way it also insures that it will take place only when my modules are initialized and running in the app, not affecting other modules, as part of the way Angular works with encapsulated CSS...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably you should declare global css rules in your html or external stylesheet.

Comment: Guess I was thinking too **Angular** about this. Yes, you're right haha.

Answer (score 16):

Angular adds unique classes to your component and rewrites the selectors of CSS added to components to only match that components unique class, before adding the CSS to the `<head>`. This is to emulate shadow DOM style encapsulation.

You can work around it by

- set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` which prevents rewriting styles for components where encapsulation is disabled
- add the CSS to the `index.html` directly. Angular doesn't rewrite CSS that is not added to components.
- use "shadow piercing CSS combinator" `::ng-deep someSelector { ... }` which also makes the CSS ignore the unique classes added to the components.

Comment: But what if you want to apply the styles to all components used inside a component? For example, assume I'm writing an app Car-Factory there is a `CarComponent` which uses `TransmissionComponent`. Now I want to use bootstrap CSS in  `CarComponent` and also in `TransmissionComponent`. I can set the `ViewEncapsulation` to `None`, but that applies the styles to entire Car-Factory which is not desired. And also, there is no `index.html` file at the `CarComponent` level

Comment: @AdityaVikasDevarapalli `:host ::ng-deep child-comonent { ... }`

Comment: Thanks, @Günter, but my use case here is to apply a stylesheet at the `:host` level, not just one particular style. Is there some way to import a stylesheet for `:host` ?

Comment: @AdityaVikasDevarapalli you can add styles to `@Component({selector: 'my-foo', styleUrls: [...]`

Comment: but that only applies styles to `CarComponent` and not `TransmissionComponent`

Comment: @AdityaVikasDevarapalli if it contains `:host ::ng-deep transmission-comonent { ... }` it will affect that too.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your CSS inside src/styles.css

or you can create your new CSS file and specify inside **.angular-cli.json** file

```
"apps": [
  "styles": ["styles.scss"]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

For angular apps created with `@angular/cli`, css needed for all components can be put in `styles.css` file which is present in `src` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this my changing your style to

```
:host .ng-invalid {
    border-left: 5px solid #a94442;
}

:host .ng-valid {
    border-left: 5px solid #42A948;
}
```

and in your child components you can set property of `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` (but by default it is ViewEncapsulation.None so you may no need to set also).

so now you should be able to user your style class in your all child components.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/ALgOw3FHmW8RsClI8Nnb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

From a command line run:

npm install file-loader style-loader --save-dev

Now in webpack.config.js add the following line to the loaders array:

{ test: /\.(eot|woff2|woff|ttf|svg)/, loader: 'file-loader'}

Now in your app.component.ts, after your import statements, add the following line:

require('style!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')

This assumes you are using the latest version of angular2/angular2-seed located here: https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed as of Nov 8 2016

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should agree to a particular strategy in this regards across your whole team.

E.g. you could set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` just like @sreeramu mentioned in his reply. But only for app (root) component.

You should take advantage of CSS encapsulation as much as you can so turning it off for several components is kinda smelly. But applying it only to one component might work fine.